# Getting KeyError: 'id' when importing a CSV file using django-import-export

Tags: django, django-admin, django-import-export

I am tring to update sqlite data by importing a csv file to django admin, only to get the error message for each single record I upload:

```
Line number: 1 - 'id'
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
import_id_fields = [self.fields[f] for f in self.get_import_id_fields()]
KeyError: 'id'
```

Here is my **models.py**, which indicates a primary key:

```
class HCPMaster(models.Model):
    external_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
    bi_external_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ...
```

The **resources.py**, which has the **import_id_fields**:

```
class HCPMasterResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = HCPMaster
        import_id_fields = ['external_id']
```

The **admin.py**:

```
class HCPMasterAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resources_class = HCPMasterResource
    
admin.site.register(HCPMaster, HCPMasterAdmin)
```

The uploaded csv file (The columns match the HCPMaster model exactly):

```
external_id,bi_external_id,name,primary_parent_name,parent_external_id,parent_parent_external_id,personal_title,administrative_title,license,network_external_id,status,verified_time,updated_time
CNC1562173,CN1183335,John,Hospital A,Hospital A,CNHABCD,Doctor,Agent,,9.36678E+17,Active,44851,45231
CNC1531568,CN1183339,Mary,Hospital B,Hospital B,CNHABCE,Doctor,Agent,,9.37537E+17,Active,44799,45231
```

I have tried every possible solution on stackoverflow and github like:

1. Specify **import_id_fields** to the actual primary key 'external_id'.
2. Specify **exclude = ['id']** in Meta Class of ModelResource.
3. Specify **fields** in Meta Class of ModelResource: List all the fields in CSV file.
4. Manually Create a id columns in the csv file with blank value.
   Sadly, none of them works.

pip list:

```
Django                 4.2.7
django-import-export   3.3.3
```

Comment: Please show every solution you've tried.  The reason would be that it would be a waste of time for others to post suggestions that you've already tried.  Also, you are importing a CSV.  What does the CSV look like?  Is there a mismatch of expected fields and actual fields?

Comment: Thanks! The question has been changed upon your advice.

Comment: In your CSV file, there are blank values for "license" column. So your HCPMaster class should have license field with null=True and blank=True

Comment: It should work due to `import_id_fields` being present in Resource and in file ([docs](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_usage.html#create-or-update-model-instances)).  Best to step through with debugger and figure out what's going wrong.  Also use `resource_classes`  not `resource_class`. Please post back if you find the problem.